# Compass only working in GPS status app, not in any other apps

Tags: sensors, compass

On my Nexus 5 (Android 6.0) the compass is working fine in the well known [GPS Status & Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2) app, but not in any other app like [Google Sky Map](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.stardroid).

To debug the problem, I installed a dedicated compass app called [Compass](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gn.android.compass), which displays the following:

[image]

This particular app happens to have a [setting for sensor accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RspPw.png). When I set it to "Above medium", the compass suddenly works. Unfortunately many of the other apps I'd like to use the compass in don't have such a setting. I have also tried the calibration move a few times, but I don't think that's the problem, because it *does* work with the right settings. It's probably not related, but I have recently used my phone for Google Cardboard, which (ab)uses the magnetic sensor for user input.

What could be causing this?